# What's wrong with this table code?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to display a Table with the following code:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{$\theta$} & \textbf{$\phi$ (\%)} & \textbf{Tiempo} & \textbf{Energía}\\ \hline
        1 & 12.5 & infinito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
          & 25 & infinito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
          & 50 & infinito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
        2 & 12.5 & infinito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
          & 25 & infinito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
          & 50 & infinito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
        3 & 12.5 & finito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
          & 25 & finito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
          & 50 & finito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
        4 & 12.5 & finito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
          & 25 & finito & Siempre decreciente\\ 
          & 50 & finito & Siempre decreciente\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However my table ends up with some weird line endings at the bottom, like this:

[image: table looks like this]

What is wrong ?

Comment: Check for some invisible character between the final `\hline` and `\end{tabular}` (possibly a "non breakable space").

Comment: In my case it works well. That exact code shows a good table for me.

Comment: If I add `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to your code, I don't get the spurious lines. Please complement your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, including everything necessary to reproduce the undesired behavior (but _only_ that).

Comment: This problem will happen if you have a trailing backslash after the last `\hline`. So look for something like: `\ `.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have something after the final `\hline` and `\end{tabular}`, then TeX starts a new line and finishes this line in `\end{tabular}`. With no further `&`, the line will contain just one cell.

If you have `\\` (my guess) after the final `\hline`, then remove it.

My second guess is some unvisible character. For example an unbreakable space (`0xA0`)
is usually not seen in the editor, but it is not ignored like an ordinary space by TeX.
Then TeX starts a new line with that char. Try to remove everything after the latest `\hline` up to the `\end{tabular}`. Or use a hex editor.

Comment: It was an invisible character. :)